# Ubuntu Samba tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I am stumped. After hours of time I haven't made any progress. I am getting the following error. Running Ubuntu 22.04. What's crazy is I have this working on another machine running the same version. I just don't know what I am doing wrong now. I've tried more than one instance of Ubuntu and have the same issue. I initially thought it was because the share was on a second hard drive but I took that out of the picture by unmounting it and sharing a folder on the same OS drive, but still getting the same error.

tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME

This happens using smbclient from an other Ubuntu instance and from windows.

```
smbclient //titan/share -U samba
Password for [WORKGROUP\samba]:
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

Here is my smb.conf.

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file

   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

[share]
  comment = share
  browsable = yes
  read only = no
  path = /home/samba
  create mask = 775
  directory = 775
  valid users = samba
```

Pemissions are 777 all the way up the path. SELinux is not involved and AppArmor has no profile set for samba.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration you have specified the share as `\\titan\share`, and that's also how you should access it, not `\\titan\samba`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. Same error still occurs with corrected command.

Comment: Since you are trying to connect on a name, it uses DNS, so do you have a DNS record for titan? Have you tried connecting on IP?

Comment: IP gives the same result. DNS is setup automatically when I setup a static ip assignment in the router.

Comment: Can you verify your samba configuration using `testparm -s`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (enforcing) SElinux, samba access to these locations might be denied, unless:

`semanage fcontext -a -t share "/home/samba(/.*)?"`

`restorecon -Rv /home/samba`

Also check for firewalls or blocked ports

And restart the samba service and check it's status